# Are there any restrictions in carrying shoes in cabin baggage?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage

As I don't have much space in my check-in luggage, I am planning to carry hiking shoes [without spikes] in my cabin luggage.

Are there any restrictions on shoes in cabin luggage? I have heard restrictions on sports equipments, so I just want to be sure about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Plenty of backpackers and other travelers only travel with cabin lugggage and so this is done quite often. They will have to go through the X-ray anyway, so keep them in the luggage and wear shoes that you can easily take on and off to pass through security smoothly.

Sport equipment refers to different things, often items of unusual size and shape, plus items that one could think of being usable as weapon (spiky, pointy, etc). Shoes and jackets, even for sporting, do not fall into that category.

Answer (score 3):

I would imagine it is OK, especially without cleats/spikes.

The only restriction that could apply is that they are too big and do not fit in the allowed hand luggage size.

Can you wear them and put your regular shoes in the luggage?

Comment: I usually wear my hiking shoes and never had any remarks about them. But they will have to go through the scanner, so take them off at security.

Comment: Depending on how much metal the shoes have or don’t have, you may get away with just keeping them on. I do usually ask to let me try to go through the scanner once with my thick winter shoes if I am wearing them and in the majority of times it works.

Answer (score 1):

If space or weight is a concern with your luggage, then I suggest you wear the bulkiest boots you have during the flight and put smaller ones into your (cabin) luggage.

Unless you have blades hidden in your shoe soles, there won't be any problem with security.   =)

Same goes for thick jackets, e.g. when you plan on going on an expedition. Just "wear" them during the flight